# Clojure STM simple program

Tags: clojure, stm

I am writing on a simple program to transform the values of two integers using Clojure's STM.
I am following the approch of Lewandowski (http://lewandowski.io/2016/01/clojure-summary/), using his function a06.

My code:

```
(defn trans [p1 p2]
  (println "a")
    (dosync
      (let [newval1 (@p1 + 50)
            newval2 (@p2 - 30)]
        (do 
          (println "b")
          (ref-set p1 newval1)
          (ref-set p2 newval2)))))

(defn main []
   (let [p1 (ref 20) p2 (ref 100)]
     (do
       (future (trans p1 p2))
       (future (trans p1 p2))
       (Thread/sleep 500))    
   (println @p1)
   (println @p2)))
```

For some reason, my function main is not getting into the "do part" of the function trans. My output is hence only:

```
a
a
20
100
=> nil
```

I added "a" and "b" to show my problem.
I am sorry if this is a very simple mistake I made but I simply don't see what is missing in my code. Every answer is much apreciated! Thank you!

Comment: BTW, do note that `(@p1 + 50)` is infix, and needs to be corrected to `(+ @p1 50)`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't think that's true. A future is backed by an entry in a threadpool. You lose the reference to the object that lets you see the result, but the threadpool still has a reference to its task. Your version succeeds correctly because you fixed the infix math - it used to throw an exception before having any side effects.

Comment: I had it in my head that the threadpool entry was weakly referenced, but could well have been thinking of a different runtime/construct entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Compare to the following, which works correctly:

```
(defn trans [p1 p2]
  (println "a")
  (dosync
   (let [newval1 (+ @p1 50)
         newval2 (- @p2 30)]
     (do
       (println "b")
       (ref-set p1 newval1)
       (ref-set p2 newval2)))))

(defn main []
  (let [p1 (ref 20) p2 (ref 100)]
    (let [f1 (future (trans p1 p2))
          f2 (future (trans p1 p2))]
      (Thread/sleep 500))
    (println (pr-str @p1))
    (println (pr-str @p2))))
```

That said, futures aren't really the ideal tool for the job when your interest is in a side effect, rather than in later retrieval of the result of the calculation itself.